# Node.js application stops running in google cloud vm

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, minecraft

I recently tried out Google Cloud for running node.js applications.
Currently, I have a node Minecraft bot (using the library Mineflayer) running on a VM instance in the compute engine at Google Cloud.

The problem I encountered was that when there is no active SSH connection from my pc to the VM, the MC bot leaves the game. When there are players online, and I close the connection to the VM, the bot leaves after a few minutes.

Is this a setting in the compute engine that I need to turn on, to keep scripts running, or could there be something else?
I am new to Google Cloud, and also pretty new to node.js, so if anyone has suggestions or fixes I would really appreciate a comment.

Comment: Im not sure about the cloud stuff, but what happens when you run the node process as (background) service ? Try to start the node process with a & at the end `node bot.js &`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried it out but the bot still left. Also, it might be worth mentioning that I have an express API running in the same application.

Comment: Hi, have you tried running the set up in a physical machine instead of the cloud? That way you will know if the issue is caused by minecraft or Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: Yes, I have done that. And it does'nt stop the process, however the same is true when I stay connected to the vm. It only stops after I close that connection.

Comment: If you start the MC bot while in the ssh session, I think the bot will use the ssh connection, So if you disconnect the session, naturally the bot will stop. Can you try to run it as a daemon or have it start automatically?

Answer (score 1):

To get around this use `screen`.

Using `screen` you can create multiple virtual terminals which will remain alive even after the SSH session ends.

- To install `screen` use:

  ```
    sudo apt install screen
  ```
- To start your server:

  ```
    sudo screen -S <SESSION_NAME> node server.js
  ```

`SESSION_NAME` would be the name of your virtual terminal.

- To exit the new virtual terminal press CTRL+A and CTRL+D in quick succession.
- To access your terminal use:

  ```
    sudo screen -r <SESSION_NAME>
  ```